# Computer fails POST

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, bios, post

I have a Dell XPS630i that fails The POST when powered on. I  recently upgraded to an SSD with 64-bit windows 7 and after having some problems with the black screen of death (turned out that two monitors using DVI wasn't supported so I just disconnected the second monitor) it worked fine. After a week (maybe less) it started to fail its POST. I left it for a couple of days and it passed it's tests again. Yesterday I turned on the computer to find that it is failing POST again. I check the bios to find nothing unusual and when the computer reboots it passes the test.

I know that POST tests fails have a broad variation of reasons for occuring but I see absolutely no reason why it should fail first time but pass after exiting the bios. The computer also runs fine after passing and it begs the question of whether I should just ignore it and press f1 to continue.

Considering that it works perfectly after this, I would assume that the main components are fine which leads me to think it might be one of the hard drives as that is the only thing that has changed other than my OS. My computer has the previously mentioned SSD, a 500gb hdd and 2 mirrored 1tb hdd (which are not currently connected). Any ideas as to why this is happening as I don't have a clue as to what would be causing this considering that it doesn't seem to affect operation of the computer?

Comment: Please give us a clue. Are there any beeps? Blinking LEDs?

Comment: No noises or lights that weren't already there.

Comment: You have said a lot, but haven't told us much about the details or what you have tried. What is the exact message that is telling you it failed. Does it indicate why? Have you updated the BIOS to support the SSD? Have you reconnected the previous drive to see if the problem still exists?

Comment: The BIOS has been updated recently and I have tried swapping out drives to no avail. There is no indication as to what is the problem on the POST screen. The problem is that there really seems to be no problem some of the time. After failing POST and coming out of the BIOS everything is fine and boots normally which is odd. It could be a coincidence that it is failing POST now that I have replace hard drives. RAM seems alright, graphics card is normal, fan is working CPU isn't over heating and there seems to be enough power.

Comment: Instead of repeating *"failing POST"* (without any further details), describe in detail what happens as this PC boots, and what is out of the ordinary that indicates that something has *"failed"*.  *"After failing POST and coming out of the BIOS everything is fine'* -- If a PC truly failed POST, then usually the PC should halt.  What you seem to be calling *"POST"* is not obvious.